# OpenGL шейдеры 1.10 проверка на наличие текстуры

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Хочу сделать шейдеры, которые будут аналогичны шейдерам которые идут стандартно, но я не знаю как определить наличие текстуры. Мне надо сделать так, чтоб если не было текстуры объект закрашивался нужным цветом, иначе текстуркой.
Я предполагаю, что ид текстуры находится в uniform sampler2D, но как сравнить его с обычным int или float?
Я пытался сделать вторую uniform sampler2D и присвоить ей ид 0, но при присвоении выдаёт ошибку "Fragment shaders error: ERROR: 0:6: 'uniform' :  cannot initialize this type of qualifier"  а при сравнении с основной выдаёт ошибку "ERROR: 0:11: '!=' :  wrong operand types  no operation '!=' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'uniform sampler2D' and a right operand of type 'uniform sampler2D' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: В OpenGL нет "отсутствия текстуры". Текстура всегда есть, она может быть неинициализирована - по умолчанию это черная. Вам придется добавить свой дополнительный флаг.

Comment: Спасибо, я это и имел в виду, а разве этого флага нет? Я же "биндю" текстуру, а когда не нужна меняю на 0, я уверен такой флаг есть

Comment: Так 0 - это тоже валидный хэндл текстуры )

Comment: Мне нужно узнать ид (или хендл), который я присваиваю через glBindTexture, там 0 - это неинициализированная текстура

Comment: Хитрость в том, что в шейдере sampler2D это ид текстурного блока (`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);`), а не самого хэндла текстуры (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);`). Вы же сами в коде делаете `glUniform1i(unf_texture, 0);`?

Comment: Спасибо, напишите это как ответ, я помечу его как верный

Comment: Нет времени оформлять (тем более вдруг я не прав и способ есть?). Если хотите можете сами запостить, я плюсик поставлю. // если что, минус на вопросе не мой, но было бы интересно увидеть мотивацию его поставившего.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда ещё поищу

Comment: @Kromster ¿А что тут неясного? Вопрос про какой-то неработающий код, при том что ОП не только не удосужился привести обязательный [mcve], но даже пояснить толком, что вообще пытается делать.

Comment: @user7860670 кажется вполне очевидно, что ТС хочет определить, назначена у него текстура или нет.

Comment: @Kromster *"Это «очевидно», сказал себе Ханстен, великолепный пример логики «блюдцепоклонников», лихой скачок через барьер несуразицы, совершенно ошеломляющий нормальный разум."* - A. Ч. Кларк "Лунная пыль" По мне так ОП пытается в шейдере определять, забиндина там текстура в семплер или нет.

Comment: @user7860670 возможно OpenGL просто не ваш конек. Справедливости ради, вопрос не про неработающий код, а про общий принцип (другими словами про определения назначенности хэндла в OpenGL / GLSL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как предложил @Kromster для определения есть ли текстура можно использовать свой флаг, например:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[0]);
glUniform1i(flagTexture, 1);
...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
glUniform1i(flagTexture, 0);
```